# How to calculate transaction limit in Firestore with multiple documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) says that the maximum number of field transformations that can be performed on a single document in a commit operation or in a transaction is 500. How would this limit be calculated with multiple documents within a single transaction?

I have a transaction that gets a single document (let's call it the "transaction document") and it loops through one of its map fields to locate other documents. Within each loop iteration, a document ID is constructed and that document is then deleted and then the transaction document is updated to reflect that delete. Therefore, each loop iteration performs 2 operations—delete a document and update a field in the transaction document.

How is the 500 calculated here? Should this transaction perform 249 iterations (to total 499 operations in the loop, plus the original document get)? Or can this transaction perform 499 iterations since only 1 document is getting hit in each iteration?

Comment: I suggest also contacting Firebase support directly for an authoritative answer, as I've never seen this sort of question come up before (and a see a lot of questions). https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support